How to filter out single properties from an Image on GEE?
I'm trying to filter out a single property from this Image on GEE but cannot figure out how to do so. I'm trying to extract "5: Coral/Algae" from "benthic_class_names" to create a binary image, where 1= is coral/algae and 0 = everything else.
Image ACA/reef_habitat/v2_0 (1 band)
type: Image
id: ACA/reef_habitat/v2_0
version: 1685069031831359
bands: List (1 element)
properties: Object (11 properties)
    benthic_class_names: List (7 elements)
    0: Unmapped
    1: Sand - Sand is any soft-bottom area dominated by fine unconsolidated sediments.
    2: Rubble - Rubble is any habitat featuring loose, rough fragments of broken reef material.
    3: Rock - Rock is any exposed area of hard bare substrate.
    4: Seagrass - Seagrass is any habitat where seagrass is the dominant biota.
    5: Coral/Algae - Coral/Algae is any hard-bottom area supporting living coral and/or algae.
    6: Microalgal Mats - Microalgal Mats

I've tried a few different things but cannot figure it out. Any help?
